# How to configure memcached for mysql innodb?

Tags: mysql, memcached

Currently we have a website running on a Centos 6.5 webserver with Direct Admin. APC was configured in the past and is working nicely, but some reading suggested to also implement memcached to cache some static tables (like for instance menu's).

As of MySQL 5.6, the innoDB tables are compatible with a mysql memcache deamon, so I started off following this guide: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached-installing.html.
The config script is ran and the deamon is installed.

However the [Drupal memcache plugin](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache) does not see memcache is running. That module is obviously checking for the php memcached deamon, while my deamon is already running in mysql.

Since both extensions are called `memcached.so`, we strongly have the feeling this is the same thing. Are there actually two different things and does Drupal not support the InnoDB memcached deamon, do I need both (php extension to access the mysql extension?), or was this supposed to be working and did we something wrong?

**Update**

The status report showed something like "not running", but one of my colleagues has installed the PHP PECL extension now and it seems to be working. But then I still don't understand what the MySQL innodb deamon plugin does. Is it not needed, or does it improve database access even more then the PHP extension would?

Comment: What more precisely does "does not see memcache is running" mean?

Comment: The status report showed something like "not running", but one of my colleagues has installed the PHP PECL extension now and it seems to be working. But then I still don't understand what the MySQL innodb deamon plugin does. Is it not needed, or does it improve database access even more then the PHP extension would?

Comment: If you're using memcached php extension watch out for this bug https://www.drupal.org/node/1954348. It doesn't always behave nicely with views caching.

Comment: @Neograph734 I am not sure if SO is the best place for this.  SuperUser may be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Memcached interface to InnoDB is a feature of MySQL to support the memcached protocol, yet with InnoDB as the back-end storage. It seems like lot of people have been confused by what this means, so I'll try to explain.

Whereas a real memcached daemon stores data in memory, MySQL stores data persistently in an InnoDB table. PHP applications can read and write data using the memcached extension, as if they're using a standard memcached in-memory store. However, they are really reading and writing rows from the InnoDB table.

This is somewhat slower than standard memcached, because it has the overhead of writing to disk is greater than accessing memory.  But it's somewhat faster than using SQL to read and write those rows, because it skips the complexity of the SQL parser and query optimizer.

That's really the new feature in MySQL: to bypass SQL, and give access directly to the InnoDB storage engine through a simple, but familiar interface. They chose memcached on the theory that many developers would be familiar with it and have tools and language support for it already.

The InnoDB memcached interface is similar to the earlier experimental plugin called HandlerSocket developed in 2010. http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.com/2010/10/using-mysql-as-nosql-story-for.html

Here's a Percona blog that shows tests of the relative speeds of InnoDB memcached versus SQL queries: http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/03/29/mysql-5-6-innodb-memcached-plugin-as-a-caching-layer/

---

Re your question in comments:

You might be misunderstanding. The data is *never* in Memcached. There is no automatic synchronization between MySQL and Memcached. The only thing is that MySQL is mimicking the API and protocol of Memcached. There's no reason that they did this, except to make the API familiar to developers.

When you use the "Memcached API for InnoDB" you're connecting your application to a port listened to by the `mysqld` daemon process. Your requests on this connections read and write rows directly in the InnoDB storage engine. There's no Memcached instance in between.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, so if I understand it right the following happens; If the data is already in loaded in memcached the data will be `php <-> memcached`, and if it has not yet been loaded into memory, or it is a set query, the data will go `php <-> memcached <-> innodb`. Which is faster then the 'traditional' `php <-> SQL <-> innodb`. Or does each request always reach the innodb layer, even it has already been loaded into the memory?

Answer (score 4):

The [InnoDB Memcached Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached.html) is a feature in MySQL >= 5.6 that runs a Memcached daemon in the existing `mysqld` process supporting the Memcached API listening on a different port (**11211** by default). Because it runs in the same process space as InnoDB, you get low-latency access to data stored in InnoDB tables and through existing, widely-available Memcached clients.

This has a few interesting use-cases:

1. Transparent support for adding InnoDB as a high-performance persistence layer to existing memcached clients/applications
2. Improved performance over SQL queries for interacting with InnoDB tables directly (especially for inserting new key/value pairs), since the simple Memcached protocol bypasses the overhead of SQL parsing and query-plan optimization
3. High-performance 'MySQL + caching layer' architecture, where the memcached daemon fetches data from from the underlying InnoDB table and serves cached data directly from local memory

Case #3 is particularly noteworthy: Although the Memcached plugin is configured by default to read/write directly to the underlying InnoDB table (`innodb_only` cache policy), it *can* be configured to use its own, separate local memory cache just like a standalone Memcached instance would, either without using InnoDB storage at all (`cache-only`), or using InnoDB as a backing store (`caching`). (Note that the [currently-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412852/how-to-configure-memcached-for-mysql-innodb/26436732#26436732) is incorrect on this point.)

Refer to the [architecture diagram](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-memcached-intro.html) from the documentation (note the 'local cache (optional)' component, which is used by the `cache-only` or `caching` cache policies):

[image]
<sub>(source: [mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/images/innodb_memcached2.jpg))</sub>

In terms of setup/installation, if you're using the Memcached plugin for anything other than a standalone key-value cache (case #1), you will need to create a mapping from Memcached keys/values to your InnoDB tables/columns by writing a row to the special `innodb_memcache.containers` table. See [Creating a New Table and Column Mapping](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-memcached-setup.html#innodb-memcached-new-table-setup) for details.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a side-track here, but nowadays you're better of using the [memcache_storage](http://drupal.org/project/memcache_storage) module. The module page has plenty of good pointers how to use the module and with what other modules it integrates nicely to have a better and faster caching for your site.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of that. Although my question was intended to be about the difference between the PECL extension and the InnoDB extension. I've already requested transfer to Stack Overflow.